# C# gif Image to MemoryStream and back (lose animation)

Tags: c#, animation, stream, gif

I have a small problem and I do not find any solutions.
I want to convert a GIF to a byte[] and then back to a GIF. I works fine but I lose the animation.

It is a perfectly animated GIF when I start (I show it in a `PictureBox` element). But after conversion I get stuck with the first frame.

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("creativetechs.com/i/tip_images/ExampleAnimation.gif");
HttpWebResponse httpWebReponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
Stream stream = httpWebReponse.GetResponseStream();
Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
img.Save(ms,img.RawFormat);
byte [] bytes = ms.ToArray();
Image img2 = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bytes));

int frames1 = img.GetFrameCount(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Time);
int frames2 = img2.GetFrameCount(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Time);
```

I also tried to use not RawFormat but `System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif`. Didn't change a thing. `frames1` is right number of frames. `frames2` is 1.

I have 2 `PictureBox` elements in my GUI. One showing `img` and the other `img2`. But `img2` is not animated while `img` is. What is wrong?

I have also tried to use serialization instead to create my byte[].

I serialized the image and deserialized it again and it didn't change anything either. How is this possible?

Comment: The GDI+ gif encoder does not support SaveAdd() nor animated gifs.

Comment: Have you considered it may be a problem with the GIF? I just tried your exact code with this [GIF](http://www.creativetechs.com/iq/tip_images/ExampleAnimation.gif) and it worked no problem. Both `frames1` and `frames2` equal 17.

Comment: And why am I able to load and visualize an animated gif from a Web ResponseStream?

Comment: ok I will try this GIF.
... No same result

Comment: There's no need to write "[not solved]" in the question title, as it will show up with a green answer count in the list when you accept an answer, so it's obvious when it is/isn't solved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you load your image from a `Stream`, the .NET framework detects that the GIF is animated. Since it knows that it will be unable to reencode an animated GIF, it tries to store the original encoding of the GIF. But this happens *after* it has read the stream and decoded the GIF. So when it tries to rewind the stream this fails and it ends up not storing the original.

When you call `Save()` it first checks whether it has the original encoding stored. But since that operation failed, it attempts to reencode the GIF. Since .NET does not have an encoder for animated GIFs, it only encodes the first frame.

If you use a `FileStream` instead it works, since a `FileStream` is seekable.

You can make your code work by loading the response into a MemoryStream first:

```
// ...
Stream stream = httpWebReponse.GetResponseStream();

MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
memoryStream.Position = 0;
stream = memoryStream;

Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
// ...
```

If you want to see what happens, enable .NET reference source debugging and note what happens in Image.EnsureSave(). You will also note that the Image-implementation already copies the Stream into a MemoryStream, so that they could fix the problem by using that instead of the original Stream.

Comment: Rasmus: Won't your solution suffer from this problem?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814675

"Additionally, if the stream was destroyed during the life of the Bitmap object, you cannot successfully access an image that was based on a stream."

The Bitmap object does not keep a reference to the stream.  If the stream is disposed, references to the Bitmap will fail.  You will get away with it when working with regular bitmaps, but if you create an animated GIF from a stream, re-drawing the animated GIF will fail on some systems.

Answer (score 2):

GDI+ does not contain any animated GIF *encoder* (just a *decoder*). So your *img.Save* will drop the animation. But you could try this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/NGif.aspx

Comment: It works perfectly if you load the gif from a file but not if you load it from a http response.

Answer (score 0):

As "Rasmus Faber" quoted on Jan 17 '12 at 20:00 ==> I was developed my image slider prog as his advise and it works so good. Thanks a lot.
My sample code are as below. Enable to load both of LPG and animation GIF by without any error and also enable to delete all un-need file.

```
Dim t1 As String
t1 = ListBox5.SelectedItem.ToString
Dim mmp As MemoryStream
mmp = New MemoryStream()

Using str As Stream = File.OpenRead(t1)
str.CopyTo(mmp)
End Using
PictureBox8.Image = Image.FromStream(mmp)
```