# How to compare two images using byte arrays

Tags: c#, image, arrays

I want to be able to convert from Byte[] to Image and vice versa.

I've this two methods from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ImageConverter.aspx?fid=337686&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick):

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    return  ms.ToArray();
}

public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```

They seem to work, but if I do:

```
byte[] pic = GetImageFromDb();
bool result = pic == imageToByteArray(byteArrayToImage(pic));
```

I get `result = false`!

Any way to correct this methods or some different functions to achieve my goal?

Thanks!

Comment: same problem here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763630/c-sharp-gif-image-to-memorystream-and-back-lose-animation

except the == stuff
use pic.equals(imageToByteArray(byteArrayToImage(pic));

Comment: @OliverBernhardt try this code `new byte[] { 1 }.Equals(new byte[] { 1 })`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `==` will compare the object references if not overridden.

Since these are two *different* `byte[]` objects, the references are different.

You need to compare the `byte[]` objects item by item in order to confirm that they are identical. You can use [`SequenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) in this case.

Comment: Additionally, the OP should read something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649444/testing-equality-of-arrays-in-c-sharp to get an idea of how to properly compare them.

Comment: @ChrisShain - The question is about having the same items in different arrays - ordering is not important there. It is _very_ important here.

Comment: @Oded Very true, I hadn't caught that. There are tons of good questions on the subject though, this one was just a (bad) example.

Answer (score 2):

`==` means that you have a reference to the same object in memory.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289/comparing-two-byte-arrays-in-net) shows how to compare byte arrays in a few different ways.

Comment: then why this returns false? `new byte[] { 1 }.Equals(new byte[] { 1 })`

Comment: @L.B: very true. Forgive me; for arrays, this does not work. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289/comparing-two-byte-arrays-in-net) for how to compare byte arrays properly. Updating my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I recently needed to write an image cropper that needed to save the fileBytes as an image. here is what I did. Hopefully this will help you.

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] fileBytes)
{
    using (MemoryStream fileStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))
    {
        return Image.FromStream( fileStream );
    }
}
```

obviously my code for the cropping/saving expands upon this. But I was able to return an Image object from the file bytes.

Answer (score 1):

When you re-encode an image, the resulting file (or byte array) can be (slightly?) different from the original version. Especially if what you retrieve from the database was a jpeg file!

So even if you compare the bytes in the arrays (instead of references) you can get differences.

**EDIT**
When you read a byte[] (containing a GIF encoded image) into a `BitMap`, those bytes are decompressed into 4 (ARGB) bytes per pixel. When you save that BitMap to a (new) gif file (or byte[]), the newly encoded file could be different (for instance, the order in which the colors are stored). So there is no guarantee that the new file (or byte[]) is identical to the old one, although the image itself isn't changed.

Comment: Why would that be?? Is there any way to avoid it?