# create a byte[] from a bmp c#

Tags: c#, image, byte, bmp

So I know there are plenty of examples of how to make a Bmp from a `byte[]`, but I have to return a `byte[]` so it can be loaded by a webpage.

I have a Bmp that I did some processing on and I want to create a new `byte[]` with those changes to the webpage.

If it matters I think the image was originally a jpeg, but ideally I would want this to work for any image format.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? How do you intend to display the image on the webpage?

Comment: We need to know what isn't working for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764280/c-sharp-image-to-byte-and-byte-to-image read this! maybe it's help you. someone can help you better when you tell thing clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.Save()` the bitmap to a MemoryStream. Return yourMemoryStream.ToArray()

Comment: Damn I forgot you could save to a stream object! Nicely done and so quickly!