# How to retrieve the User image from ActiveDirectory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I had my solution to get user image from Active Directory, I did my code well but I cannot how to add `ImageURL` to the image that come from Active Directory

```
byte[] data = user.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"].Value as byte[];

if (data != null)
{
   using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(data, 0, data.Length))
   {
       s.Position = 0;
       s.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

       //here I want to add the imageurl to Image controll
   }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764280/c-sharp-image-to-byte-and-byte-to-image