# Image.Save requires additional parameters

Tags: c#, arrays, image, byte

simple question that I simply can't seem to find a decent answer for.

i'm trying to convert a memory image to a byte array in order to upload it as a Base64String

```
Bitmap CapSc()
{
    using(Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
    {
       using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
       {
         g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
       }
       return bitmap;
    }
}

Image toUpload;
toUpload = (Image)CapSc();

public static byte[] GetBytesFromImage(Image img)
    {
        if (img == null) return null;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(stream, img.RawFormat);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }

GetBytesFromImage(toUpload);
```

however the 'img.Save' constantly returns errors where it seems to require a third paramater of EncoderParamaters, no sample code or developer solutions on MSDN say this is neccessary but it constantly returns errors if i have it present or not.

the specific error is 'Paramter cannot be null. Paramater name: encoder'

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What `Image` type is this? There are various different ones across different frameworks...

Comment: System.Drawing.Image, returned originally as bitmap and cast.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Image to Byte\[\] and Byte\[\] to Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764280/c-sharp-image-to-byte-and-byte-to-image)

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use `stream.GetBuffer()` even if `Save` succeeds - you should use `ToArray`. The buffer will be larger than the data requires (usually).

Comment: i've tried using the solutions in that answer as well as multiple others, they all give similar errors of requiring the additional paramater.

Comment: thanks for the heads up on ToArray, i've changed it.

Comment: Can you share the code of creating the img object?

Comment: I have multiple versions of CapSc for different reasons, this is more of a test one, but is the one i've been using for the above errors. (added to OP)

Comment: Is this a compile-time error or a runtime error? Looks like runtime. Just confirming.

Comment: try changing `img.RawFormat` to `ImageFormat.Jpg` - it is wanting an encoder for whatever underlying format thats in

Comment: its a runtime error yes, I have tried PNG and jpeg with previous attempts, I'll try it now with this.

Comment: on mine, the initial `ImageFormat` reported by RawFormat for a scrncap is an odd GUID key (undefined? internal?); using `ImageFormat.Jpg` saves fine and easier than getting an encoder unless you need to set some special settings or use a specific format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your Image.Save call (where you don't specify an encoder), the framework is making this call:

```
ImageCodecInfo encoder = format.FindEncoder();
```

and then passing that result into the overload that does specify an encoder.

What's happening is that `FindEncoder` is returning `null` in your case. So the system can't find an encoder that works for whatever `ImageFormat` is specified by the `RawFormat` property.

To see what Codecs are available on your machine, you could iterate through the result of

```
ImageCodeInfo.GetImageEncoders()
```

Or you could just go with one you know is there like jpeg :)

Comment: `RawFormat` is a property of type `ImageFormat` not an actual format.  The problem is that whatever format it is in, it cant find an encoder for it.

Comment: That's what I meant, but looking at what I wrote that wasn't at all obvious. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much exactly what I've been working on the past month.  Provided I didn't miss anything, this should work (you may need an extra `using` statement or two):

```
ImageCodecInfo codec;
EncoderParameters myEPS;

public YourConstructor() {

    codec = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    myEPS = new EncoderParameters(1);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
    EncoderParameter myEP = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 60L); // 0-100 quality level
    myEPS.Param[0] = myEP;

}

private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
{
    ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

    foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
    {
        if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
        {
            return codec;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static byte[] GetBytesFromImage(Image img)
{
    if (img == null) return null;
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(stream, codec, myEPS);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```