# How to convert byte[] of PNG into jpeg

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a byte[] of image data (of png type) and I want to convert it into jpeg type image. What would be the best way of doing it in Windows Phone 8?

Comment: Check this link once.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764280/c-sharp-image-to-byte-and-byte-to-image

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using(var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
   //bytes is byte[] containing the image data
   var image = Image.FromStream(stream);
   image.Save(File.OpenWrite("MyImage.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: Remember to dispose the stream and the image.

Comment: True! I didn't include that, but it is very important!

Comment: Also, do replace File.OpenWrite() for a new Stream, like MemoryStream, if you don't want to write the file to the filesystem.

Comment: Seems like System.Drawing namespace is not available in WP8 and hence, we cannot do image.Save()