# Download animated GIF

Tags: c#, .net, gif, animated

I'm using the below to grab an animated gif off the web. However, upon saving this to disk, I lose the frames in the gif, and it no longer animates. Not sure whether the problem is in the below method, or whether it's when I'm saving it, but any feedback on why the below wouldn't work appreciated. The method is working - just not creating a proper animated gif file.

```
public Image getImage(String url)
{
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse httpWebReponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = httpWebReponse.GetResponseStream();
    return Image.FromStream(stream, true, true);
}

Image im = getImage(url)
im.Save(pth,ImageFormat.Gif);
```

Comment: Can you use the WebImage class? Alternatively, don't even treat it as an Image, which would process it, but rather just as a stream of bytes and save that to a file with a .gif extension; if what they uploaded was an animated gif, it would be save it correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# gif Image to MemoryStream and back (lose animation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763630/c-sharp-gif-image-to-memorystream-and-back-lose-animation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not create an `Image` from the stream ([it will only store the first frame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8900891/146622)). Instead, you should write the contents of the `Stream` directly to disk using, for example, the [`Stream.CopyTo` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx) to copy the content to a `FileStream` you created for the destination file.

```
using (Stream stream = httpWebReponse.GetResponseStream())
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
{
    stream.CopyTo(fs);
}
```

Comment: Or alternatively a MemoryStream?

Comment: @I4V "_Since .NET does not have an encoder for animated GIFs, it only encodes the first frame._" ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8900891/146622))

Comment: Great, now someone just needs to update Rasmus's answer with `using` statements for all of the copy-and-paste coders here.