# Get dynamically generated image into win form

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to get an image via `HttpWebRequest` and show it in the win form `imagebox`. While tracking the request via Fiddler ImageView tab I can see that image can be seen correctly but while reading the stream I got `Stream was not readable` error on

```
Image img = Image.FromStream(stream).
```

What am I missing?

```
HttpWebRequest req =  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("[URL here]");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();    
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);   // ERROR occurs here

stream.Close();
```

Comment: It's kinda hard to say, because the question does not show what image format is generated. It could be possible that the stream isn't completely downloaded, can you compare the `response.ContentLength` and the `stream.Length`? The `Image.FromStream` expects that the image is completely within the stream. Maybee you should try to copy it first to a memorystream until the full ContentLength is downloaded.

Comment: I am looking an req.ContentLegth = -1 and  stream Length = 'stream.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' So not sure what is wrong since in Fiddler I got image shown. Also if I add responseData = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd(); it seems getting correct string

Answer (score 0):

After some digging found an answer here [C# gif Image to MemoryStream and back (lose animation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763630/c-sharp-gif-image-to-memorystream-and-back-lose-animation):

```
HttpWebRequest req =  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("[URL here]");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();    
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
memoryStream.Position = 0;
stream = memoryStream;
Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);   

stream.Close();
```